# Difference between Message Builder and Message Formatter and how to use message relays?

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, messageformat, wso2-esb

I m constructiong a POC. I am trying to access facebook's graph api using wso2 esb. But it seems that i m not getting the complete json data. So i decided to use Message Relays as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750309/wso2-esb-unable-to-convert-complete-json-data-to-xml)
But while searching for an example of how to use it i came across 2 terms namely : Message Builders & Formatters. Can any one explain me the difference between these two. Also I was unable to find a working example with sufficient explanation to use Message Relays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message Builder : A concepts that comes from AXis2. When a message comes through a given transport(HTTP) to a wso2 esb we need to build a SOAP message out of that (eg. convert JSON to SOAP/XML) based on the message's content type.

Message Formatter : When a message goes out from ESB, again based on the output content type, the message should be converted to the required format. (eg: SOAP to JSON)

Binary Relay : Please refer [this](http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-setup-binary-relay-in-wso2-esb.html) post.