# WSO2 returning string as infinity number

Tags: json, wso2, infinity

We are using WSO2 as our API manager to communicate with our backend (nodeJS) services. We are seeing a strange issue with one endpoint where we are requesting a product JSON and are getting a JSON parsing error because of an Infinity number. The original data contains a string however which is "3E10266". When we request the product JSON from Mongo directly from the service we get the correct string back:

`{
  "_id": 800285,
  "SupplierReferenceDescription": "3E10266",
  "SupplierReferenceNumber": "3E10266",
}`

However requesting this through WSO I get the following:

`{
    "_id":800285,
    "SupplierReferenceDescription":3E+10266,
    "SupplierReferenceNumber":3E+10266
}`

Which cannot be parsed by our frontend service. It looks like WSO2 is doing some translations on the JSON, can I disable this behaviour? I have found an issue that looks like mine but no clear solution is given: [json conversion issue in wso2 API Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732828/json-conversion-issue-in-wso2-api-manager)

Comment: Have you find any solution ?